# Agenda-view hiding tabbar

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, aquamacs, tabbar

I am currently using Aquamacs 3.4, Emacs 25.3.50.1, and Org mode 9.2.5 and I typically have my frame split vertically into 2 windows. Each window carries 2+ different buffers whose names are in the tabs above. Here's an example:

[image]

When I switch to agenda-view with C-c a, the tab bar and buffers over my right window (where the agenda shows) disappear as shown here:

[image]

When I exit the agenda with q, the right tab bar does not return and, instead of the original 2+ buffers in that window, I am left with only 1.

[image]

At this point, if I kill the buffer on the right, the other (now hidden) buffer in the right window is revealed. Furthermore, I can M-x tabbar-mode once (getting rid of all tabbars) and then M-x tabbar-mode again to reveal all tabbars correctly again.

Ultimately, my problem seems to be that agenda-view is turning off tabbar-mode specifically in the window it opens. As it stands now, my fix is to turn off all tabbars and then turn them back on again, but it's a little bit of a pain.

Has anyone experienced this behavior and know of a way to disable it? Thanks for any info!

Comment: As far as I am aware, the `*Org Agenda*` buffer never used to mess with the `header-line-format`.  Please update your question to include what version of `org-mode` you are using and perhaps a minimal recipe so that the forum participants can reproduce what you are seeing.  I would also suggest that you look at the value for the `header-line-format` in the buffer/window with the problem and see if it is set to `nil` or something else instead of the standard tabbar stuff ...  Also, check to see whether your tabbar grouping rules exclude the buffer(s) that you think have problems displaying it.

Comment: I've updated the post and added some images hopefully to make things a little bit clearer. And I'll take a look at your suggestions.... this is a learning moment here.

Comment: Just a little update - I filed a bug report with Aquamacs and they got back to and are looking into this little problem. It seems that they can partially replicate what is going on. Is anyone else able to replicate this behavior?

Comment: Add yet another update: it's not that the buffers disappear - if I kill the buffer on the right in the last image above, it will reveal the other other buffers hanging out underneath. So it really is just the tabbar that disappear. At this point if I M-x tabbar-mode, they all disappear, and then if i run that command again, all the tabs come back in their former glory where they should be. I'm gonna edit above to reflect this.

Comment: Aquamacs contains its own modifications to the underlying Tabbar by David Ponce ... and, Aquamacs has tons of other custom changes that are not present in the generic / vanilla Emacs for OSX/MacOS:  https://emacsformacosx.com   The user-base for the latter is much larger -- so it may take some time for an Aquamacs-specific answer to this particular question in this forum ....

Comment: So, a work around would be to M-x tabbar-mode 2 times right after I exit agenda-view. It's a little wonky, but it'd work for the time being. My abilities in Emacs however are pretty limited. Would you know how I might add this in my init file or where I can find the actual command hitting q in agenda-view calls?